# How to turn an element into a variable

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="font-bold uppercase mt-8">Upcoming Release</div>
```

Hey so I am trying to turn text on a website into a varable.

The part that I am trying to get is the "Upcoming release" and make it equal to the variable "question"

This is the current code that I have

```
var question = document.getElementsByClassName('font-bold uppercase mt-8')
```

I have tried many things but nothing seems to work.

***UPDATE!!!***

So I tried running this code in order to search the question in google after a specific set of time.

```
function searchQuestion() {
var question = document.getElementsByClassName('mb-4 font-bold');
    for (var i = 0; i < question.length; i++) {
    var text = question[i].innerText;
     console.log(text);
  }
  
  window.open('https://google.com/search?q='+text, '_blank');  
}

setTimeout(searchQuestion, 5000);
```

At this current moment in time, the element `mb-4 font-bold` does NOT exist yet, but while testing, it is picking up the element `mb-4 text-3xl cols:text-5xl font-bold leading-none` and it is searching what is in that element rather than what it is in `mb-4 font-bold`. How do I make it so that it ONLY searches the element `mb-4 font-bold`

If the element doesn't exist yet shouldn't it just search `undefinded`?

I am a new coder so any and all help will be taken into consideration. Thankyou

Comment: variables should have no white spaces. You need to remove the spaces on the texts

Answer (score 1):

`Document.getElementsByClassName()` return a list of elements, so in your case, to get the first one only, use destructing assignment to grab that

```js
var [question] = document.getElementsByClassName('font-bold uppercase mt-8')

console.log(question)
```

```html
<div class="font-bold uppercase mt-8">Upcoming Release</div>
```

---

#### Reference

[Document.getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

> returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class name(s)

[Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

> ```
> const x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
> const [y, z] = x;
> console.log(y); // 1
> console.log(z); // 2
> ```

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` will returns an array of elements.

```js
var question = document.getElementsByClassName('font-bold uppercase mt-8');
for (var i = 0; i < question.length; i++) {
  var text = question[i].innerText;
   console.log('text => ', text);
}
```

```html
<div class="font-bold uppercase mt-8">Upcoming Release</div>
```